# How to query AWS using boto3 to find if the IMDSv2 is enforced in an EC2 instance or not

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

Is there any function in boto3 that may tell if IMDSV2 is enabled or not ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
import boto3

ec2 = boto3.client('ec2')
instance_id = 'i-xxx'
res = ec2.describe_instances(InstanceIds=[instance_id])
metadata_options = res['Reservations'][0]['Instances'][0]['MetadataOptions']
http_tokens = metadata_options['HttpTokens']
state = metadata_options['State']

if http_tokens == 'required' and state == 'applied':
    print(f"IMDSv2 is enforced in the EC2 instance with id {instance_id}")
else:
    print(f"IMDSv2 is not enforced")
    print(http_tokens, state)
```